# Java Spring get data from html form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple application which involves a jsp page (which is just a textarea to enter a query and a submit button) a Query class (very simple class shown below) and a QueryController to interact with the two. I am trying to have the QueryController print to console to test it but no output is being printed to `Standard.out` .  Clicking the submit button takes me to `http://localhost:8080/<PROJECT_NAME>/?queryField=<QUERY_TEXT>` which results in a 404 error since it is not a valid webpage. The three [simple] classes are shown below. Help is appreciated.

Query class:

```
public class Query {

    private String query;
    public String getQuery() {
         return query;
    }
    public void setQuery(String query) {
         this.query = query;
    }
}
```

query.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>

<form action="query" method="post" commandName="queryForm">
<textarea name="queryField" cols="55" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my simple QueryController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/query")
public class QueryController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("queryForm") Query query,
        Map<String, Object> model) {

    // for testing purpose:
    System.out.println("query (from controller): " + query.getQuery());

    return "someNextPageHere";
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `GET` on a form post?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml and the context file in your code?! 404 means it does not regconize the mapping page?! Have you declared the annotation scan?!

Comment: @Kenny Tai Huynh web.xml is added and ChiefTwoPencils I'm not sure what you are suggesting to do differently.

Comment: The controller expects post request and your form method is get http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Do you have a welcome page defined? If yes, is that being shown when you access `http://localhost:8080/<PROJECT_NAME>`?

Comment: Have you deployed your project (check the tomcat you are using)?  Dumb question: Are you using the right name? `/<PROJECT_NAME>/` know that it is caseSensitive so: `/SimpleProject/` guessing by your web.xml

Comment: @James Jithin yes if I visit that URL then my query.jsp page will successfully display. It is when I then type something in teh query box and hit submit that I am expecting it to print the query text to console. however, this is not happening

Comment: Alright, do you have any other Java file created for configuring Spring?

Comment: @James Jithin no i do not. I am using maven and have a pom.xml which contains all the spring dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would need more configuration to `Spring` modules to get this working. You may go with `Option 1 - with web.xml` or `Option 2 - without web.xml`:

### Option 1 (web.xml)

**1.** Modify your `web.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>SimpleProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProjectServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                 /WEB-INF/config/SimpleProjectServlet-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProjectServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>query.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**2.** Create file with path - `WEB-INF/config/SimpleProjectServlet-servlet.xml`

**3.** Add following contents to the file created in Step 2. You would need to edit the Spring version references:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myproject" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**4.** Set right package name as you have in the above configuration at `context:component-scan`

### Option 2 (non-web.xml)

**1.** Delete your `web.xml`

**2.** Add `Java Config` for annotation based `Spring MVC`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mycompany.myproject" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**3.** Modify `SpringWebConfig` with the right package at `@ComponentScan`

**4.** Add `Java Config` for `WebApplication`. Create a class extending `WebApplicationInitializer` with required configurations:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

    public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            ctx.register(SpringWebConfig.class);
            ctx.setServletContext(container);

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                    "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            servlet.addMapping("/");
        }
    }
```

### Update

Here we had few configuration part that was resulting in this error:

1. `DispatcherServlet` was configured to accept url with `views/*`
2. Deployment Descriptor did not have `src\main\java` to `WEB-INF\classes`
3. User had `Spring 3` running on `Tomcat 8` which defaults to `JDK-8` and `ASM Loader` could not load files. Had to move to Spring version `4.0.1-RELEASE`

Comment: I tried your option #1 and have updated my post with your suggestions. The same issue is persisting though- nothing printing in console

Comment: Could you name your textarea to `query` instead of `queryField`? If that doesn't work, for debugging purpose, set your model attribute to required=false. Also, when the app starts, do you the mapping `/query` being displayed?

Comment: tried renaming the textarea with no luck. and no the url that shows at launch is http://localhost:8080/GCImage/

Comment: For debugging, rename `processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("queryForm") Query query, Map<String, Object> model)` to `processRegistration()` and check if method gets called.

Comment: after doing so, the same result is happening, 404 at  localhost:8080/GCImage and  localhost:8080/GCImage/query. and no stacktrace errors

Comment: Set the URL as `/` in web.XML for QueryServlet.

Comment: Sigh- no still not working. Added a bounty to the question for you if you can figure it out

Comment: @peggy, are you available to work on this and fix it now? Do not need a bounty for such a minor thing.

Comment: I will be available in an hour. I'll comment again on this to notify you and invite you to a chat when you respond. your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90806/discussion-between-james-jithin-and-peggy).

Comment: @peggy, thanks for accepting the answer! We really had a challenging time. :D

Comment: Of course! Won't allow me to give you the bounty for another 6 hrs but its on the way

Comment: Hey, no! We will solve something complex and then take the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You query.jsp file need some change. From:

```
<textarea name="queryField" cols="55" rows="1"></textarea>
```

To:

```
<textarea name="queryField" path="query" cols="55" rows="1"></textarea>
```

You need to specify path attribute in order to use Spring form handling. Need of path attribute: it maps the form element (text area in this case) to a variable of POJO class (private String query of Query class).

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thanks a lot, I could kiss you right now. You solved my problem with that `path`,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a config file and in your web.xml you should add the declaration for it like:
 web.xml

```
...
<!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
...
```

in your appServlet-servlet.xml, you should declare the annotation scan like:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="abc.xyz"/>
```

Hope this help!